# How to convert 5min timestamp intervals to 1min intervals in SQL keeping the other information?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, resolution, intervals

I saw one or two topics asking about the opposite (turning 1min timestamp into 5min or other timestamp intervals). But I quite do not get the idea of programming this.

This is my input table:

```
timestamp     Food      Beverage
15:00:00      Pizza      Coke
15:05:00      Burger     Coke
15:10:00      Hotdog     Pepsi
   …             …        …
```

And this would be the output I want:

```
timestamp   Food    Beverage
 15:00:00   Pizza   Coke
 15:01:00   Pizza   Coke
 15:02:00   Pizza   Coke
 15:03:00   Pizza   Coke
 15:04:00   Pizza   Coke
 15:05:00   Burger  Coke
 15:06:00   Burger  Coke
 15:07:00   Burger  Coke
 15:08:00   Burger  Coke
 15:09:00   Burger  Coke
 15:10:00   Hotdog  Pepsi
 15:11:00   Hotdog  Pepsi
    …         …       …
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `cross join`:

```
select dateadd(minute, v.m, timestamp) as timestamp,
       food, beverage
from t cross join
     (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)) v(m);
```

You can also do this with an explicit `select`/`union all`:

```
select dateadd(minute, v.m, timestamp) as timestamp,
       food, beverage
from t cross join
     (select 0 as m union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) v(m);
```

Comment: I love the values part to generate rows on the fly if you know in advance the number or rows you need.  I didn't know you can do that.  It took me awhile to figure out the v(m) notation.  Is it possible to have more than one column?

Comment: @Earl . . . Yes.  The `VALUES()` row constructor is very useful.

Comment: I don't know why I can not run it in Microsoft SQL Server. It says - Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: @zhivab . . . I think the table values constructor has been in SQL Server since version 2008.

Comment: I think it was a problem with values because the second approach worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DATEADD**.  The parameter input **N** means minute.

The **ROW_NUMBER** will increment the timestamp per row.

```
DECLARE @interval varchar(10) = 5

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data

SELECT timestamp='15:00:00',Food='Pizza',Beverage='Coke'
INTO #data
UNION ALL SELECT timestamp='15:05:00',Food='Burger',Beverage='Coke'
UNION ALL SELECT timestamp='15:10:00',Food='Pizza',Beverage='Pepsi'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TAB 
CREATE TABLE #TAB (id int)

EXEC ('INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT TOP '+@interval+ ' ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) FROM sys.columns')

SELECT timestamp=CAST(DATEADD(n,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp,food,beverage ORDER BY Food),timestamp) as time) , Food,Beverage
FROM #data
CROSS JOIN #TAB
ORDER BY 1
```

The output will be:

```
+------------------+--------+----------+
|    timestamp     |  Food  | Beverage |
+------------------+--------+----------+
| 15:01:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Coke     |
| 15:02:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Coke     |
| 15:03:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Coke     |
| 15:04:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Coke     |
| 15:05:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Coke     |
| 15:06:00.0000000 | Burger | Coke     |
| 15:07:00.0000000 | Burger | Coke     |
| 15:08:00.0000000 | Burger | Coke     |
| 15:09:00.0000000 | Burger | Coke     |
| 15:10:00.0000000 | Burger | Coke     |
| 15:11:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Pepsi    |
| 15:12:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Pepsi    |
| 15:13:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Pepsi    |
| 15:14:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Pepsi    |
| 15:15:00.0000000 | Pizza  | Pepsi    |
+------------------+--------+----------+
```